# Checking if values in row in table already exists before adding in Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a UserService join table which looks as so:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "service_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "service_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "service_id": 2,
        "user_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "service_id": 3,
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "service_id": 3,
        "user_id": 2
    }
]
```

When creating a new UserService I don't want the user to be able to add an entry if the values already exist. My current if statement is currently returning the else statement. What am i doing wrong here?

```
@bp.route('/user/<userid>/add-service/<serviceid>', methods=['POST'])
def add_service_to_user(userid, serviceid):

    user = db_session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).first()
    service = db_session.query(Service).filter(Service.id == serviceid).first()

    all_user_services = db_session.query(UserService).all()

    for service in all_user_services:
        if serviceid == service.service_id and userid == service.user_id:
            return jsonify({'Message': f'User with id: {userid} already has Service with id: {serviceid}'})
    else:
        return 'hello'
```

Comment: If you need the pair _{ service_id user_id }_ to be unique, then enforce just that using a unique constraint and handle the error from trying to add a second entry with the same values. Query + check will always suffer of TOCTOU and you can end up with multiple entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that on the database side, simply use the ***and*** operator in the `.filter()`

```
.query(Service).filter(Service.id == serviceid && Service.user_id == userid).first()
```

also you may want to define types for the `serviceid` and `userid` parameters since they are integers.
the code may look like

```
@bp.route('/user/<int:userid>/add-service/<int:serviceid>', methods=['POST'])
def add_service_to_user(userid, serviceid):

    service = db_session.query(Service).filter(Service.id == serviceid && Service.user_id == userid).first()

    if service is not None:
        return jsonify({'Message': f'User with id: {userid} already has Service with id: {serviceid}'})
    else:
        return 'hello'
```